# How can I make these table columns adaptive so that they remain centered?

Tags: tables, multirow, arrays, columns, booktabs

I'm trying to create a table that can adapt its column height so that when the text length increases, `column-width` stays the same but `column height` adapts. Also, I'd like this table to have the text remain centered.

Here's what I've got so far. The problem is that when there is more text in the middle `column` in doesn't translate to the next line or remain centered as I'd like it to.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|M{5cm}|P{5cm}|M{5cm}|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Control Variables}}   &   \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Description}}   & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Value}}\\ 
    &&\\ \hline % End of Header
    \multirow{3}{*}{\text{Humidity}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\text{Humidity}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\text{Humidity}} \\
    &&\\
    &&\\ \hline 
    \multirow{3}{*}{\text{Temperature inside Freezer}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\text{Humidity}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\text{Humidity}} \\
    &&\\
    &&\\ \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{\text{Room Temperature}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\text{Nothing.}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\text{Humidity}} \\
    &&\\
    &&\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: What's the purpose of `\text` and all the `\multicolumn` commands here? Do you want a  rows to be equally tall regardless of their contents or do you want rows with single line contents to be smaller that rows with multiple line contents? Does "centered"  refer to horizontally or vertically centered?

Comment: @nocomment something like the answer below

Comment: @leandriis Yes, I want the rows to be equally tall. Centering refers to both vertical and horizontal centering (sorry for not clarifying that before). Meaning, I want to enter a sentence in the 'Description' row, while 'Variable' row has one word - and they should be centered within that row.

Comment: @nocomment: Is https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dORE.png closer to the output you want to obtain?

Comment: @nocomment, any news? No one answer fulfill your expectation? No one deserve to be accepted? As I see, so far you not accept any answer on your question :-(

Comment: @Zarko Hey, I must have forgotten to do so, hopefully it's okay now :)

Comment: @nocomment, and no one answer deserve to be accepted? So far you not accept any of answers received on your questions :-(. By this you inform comunity here, that so far any of your problems hasn't be solved ...

Answer (score 1):

If i understood the question correctly, the problem is how to set table, were cells contents can be automatically broken in mire lines and they are horizontal and vertical centered.

This can be simple achieve with use of the:

- `tabularx` packages with modified `X` columns type as done in the first example in the next MWE, or
- by `tabularray` package, where the column features is simple to setup.

In both cases the package `multirow` is not needed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{tabularray}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
By use of the \verb+tabularx+ package:
    \begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|C|C|C|}
    \hline
\textbf{Control Variables}   
            & \textbf{Description}
                        & \textbf{Value}    \\
    \hline % 
Humidity    & Humidity  & Humidity          \\
    \hline
Temperature inside Freezer 
            & Humidity  & Humidity          \\
    \hline
Room Temperature 
            & Nothing  & Humidity           \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Caption}
\label{tab:tabularx}
    \end{table}

By use of the \verb+tabularray+ package:
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {*{3}{X[c,m]}},
             rowsep  = 3pt,
              row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
             }
Control Variables
            &   Description 
                        &   Value   \\
Humidity    & Humidity  & Humidity  \\
Temperature inside Freezer
            & Humidity  & Humidity  \\
Room Temperature
            & Nothing  & Humidity   \\
\end{tblr}
    \caption{Caption}
\label{tab:tabularray}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"column-width stays the same but column height adapts"  and "want the rows to be equally tall" seem to be somewhat contradicting requests.

In the following MWE, cell's contents are vertically and horizontally centered, while the row height adapts to the length of the text inside of them:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|M{3.5cm}|P{3.5cm}|M{3.5cm}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Control Variables}   &   \textbf{Description}   & \textbf{Value}\\[3pt] \hline % End of Header
    Humidity & Humidity & Humidity \\[3pt]\hline 
    Temperature inside Freezer & Humidity & Humidity \\[3pt] \hline
    Room Temperature & Nothing. & Humidity \\[3pt]\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,lipsum} 

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Scenario}\label{tab3}
        \begin{tabular}{  M{3cm}P{5cm}M{3cm}}
            \toprule
            Col 1& Col 2 &Col3 \\
            \cmidrule(l){1-1}\cmidrule(l){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
            \addlinespace
            \addlinespace
            1  &\lipsum[1]& 3  \\
            \addlinespace
            4 &5 & 6\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```